# "Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm using Discord.js V12

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel by ID

I got the channel ID and stored it in **ChRules** using this code below

```
const ChRules = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === '│rules-and-info').id
```

So when I try and send a message to a channel by ID I use the code below

```
client.channels.cache.get(ChRules).send("Follow the rules");
```

but for some reason, I get the error

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined**

I have my bot in a single server so I can't get why I'm getting this error

I've `client` defined as `const client = new Discord.Client();`

Comment: How is `client` defined?

Comment: `const client = new Discord.Client();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get the id of the channel then get the channel with the id. You just need to get the channel, not it's id. You also really should supply a guild. So do this:

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.find(c => c.name === 'The Server');
const ChRules = guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === '│rules-and-info');
ChRules.send("Follow the rules");
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
const ChRules = client.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === '│rules-and-info')
ChRules.send("SEND");
```